# Add data to a XML file each day (performance focused)

Tags: java, xml

So I need to setup a small java program that produces an XML files containing all the data I have processed each month.

My input data consist of a XML file produced each day, and my output file must contain all the data from each day of the month. I have to produce the output file each day and not only at the end of the month.

The input files consist of several thousands of nodes so the output file will be quite big (maybe 1-2 gb) and performances are important. And the data are quite sensitive so the fiability and security of this programm must be on point.

I'm thinking about doing each day :

1) If first day of the month, create a new output file

2) Add input data of the day into the output file

First I'm wondering if for task 2 I should add the input data to the XML file or rewrite it totally each time ? What's the best in terms of performance ? And which xml library is the best for this kind of tasks ?

Then I'm wondering if saving each days data into an intermediary file that is easy to read wouldn't be better for performance ?

So the algo would be each day :

1) If first day of the month, create a new output file and a new intermediary file (JSON or text or ….)

2) Add data of the day into intermediary file

3) Produce output file from intermediary file

What do you guys think ?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance

Comment: If you do not need to modify input file then you do not need to parse XML. Just read from one file and dump to another

Comment: I actually need to do some formating from the input file, I forgot to mention it but I have to calcul some properties and re-arrange the data for each element.